# In Heroku Sendgrid, is there a way to see how many emails have my app sent today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sendgrid

I have a Rails 3.0.5 app hosted in heroku. To send emails I use Sendgrid. Im in the free plan but it has a 200 email daily limit. I want to know if there is a way in Rails or in this addon "Sendgrid", to see how many emails have been sent today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Heroku Sendgrid Stats](https://github.com/hone/heroku-sendgrid-stats) plugin

Answer (score 3):

Look at the SendGrid API..

REST GET request to:

```
https://sendgrid.com/apiv2/reseller.account.json?api_user=username&api_key=secureSecret&task=overview&user=customer@example.com
```

Source: [AccountOverview API](http://sendgrid.com/documentation/display/reseller/manage/method/api/task/AccountOverview/version/v2)

Will return something like:

> ```
> <result>
>   <overview>
>     <reputation>100</reputation>
>       <requests>50000</requests>
>       <package>Silver Package</package>
>       <credits_allowed>50000</credits_allowed>
>       <credits_used>100000</credits_used>
>       <credits_remain>0</credits_remain>
>       <credits_overage>50000</credits_overage>
>       <billing_start_date>2010-08-30</billing_start_date>
>       <billing_end_date>2010-09-29</billing_end_date>
>       <billing_process_date>2010-09-30</billing_process_date>
>     </overview>
> </result>
> ```

(Edited due to linking the wrong API page).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was to click on the SendGrid add-on in your app on Heroku. The main screen will tell you how many emails were sent today. If you click on the "Email Activity" tab you can see all of the emails that were sent.